# HTML redirect page markup

Tags: html

I have an HTML error page which I am looking to redirect users from. For example; if the user receives the error page then they will be instantly redirected to a webpage (http://www.domain.com/).

How can I do this in pure HTML and nothing else so it will work in all browsers?
What markup should I use?

Comment: Why do you _need_ to do it in _just_ html?

Comment: You could also use javascript...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.the-domain-you-want-to-redirect-to.com"></HEAD>
```

where content equals the time in seconds to redirect (say you want to pause on that page, then the page where you want to redirect to.

Make sure you include this in the head of the error page.

Comment: @CosmoPosmo - No. Not all browsers. There are literally _thousands_ of different browsers with different behaviors.

Comment: Yes, Cosmo, it works in all major browsers.  While it is true that it wouldn't work in AlientWebguy's browser, for instance, if you are looking for Chrome, FF, Safari, IE or Opera, then, yes.

Comment: The number of browsers that would be built that would, say, strip meta tags like AlienWebguy's browser, is such a small number as to be unimportant to you.  What I mean is, you can NEVER develop for everything out there or you'd never get a project finished.  You COULD use PHP to do a server-side refresh if you know enough PHP (it is actually very easy to do, there are plenty of tutorials, it is really a few lines of code), and this might cover you.  However, you have to make sure YOUR server supports PHP (I'm betting it does) and learn how to write the code.

Comment: The point is, add a meta tag refresh and probably 99% of browsers out there will refresh your page for you.

Comment: Using a meta tag in the <head> section is the only html-only, non PHP, non Javascript way I know of.  I think some users comments have you thrown for a loop.  That there are thousands of browsers out there is true, but the unbelievably vast majority of browsers used are your main browsers like Chrome, FF, IE, Opera, Safari, the dreaded IE (that is 50% of browser use right there) and the mobile browsers for iPhone, Android, Blackberry, and the older browsers for non smartphones, ALL of which support meta tags.  To develop for a browser that maybe a couple hundred people use world-wide? Don't.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript, you can put these three lines:

`<script language="javascript">`

`window.location.href = "http://example.com"`

`</script>`